# Google Sheets - If? ISBLANK? Not sure how to pull this one off

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula, google-sheets-dates, google-sheets-timestamp

I am trying to find a formula for the following:

If cell A1 has a date in it, copy that date to cell F1.  If A1 does not have a date in it, copy the date from cell B1 into cell F1.

I have a receipt tracking form that sends data to a spreadsheet.  The form will use the current date every time I make an entry.  That's great if I pull my phone out right then and there and enter the receipts values.  That obviously doesn't always happen.  I might end up waiting till Friday evening to enter them all for the week.  So I also included a date entry on the form so that I can enter the actual date of the transaction.

I would like a formula that will allow me to choose, if there is a manual date entered into the form and that date goes to cell B1, then use that date and ignore the date that is in cell A1.

Comment: Welcome. Are you familiar with [ISDATE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9061381)? Returns true for a date and false if not a date. Combine that with an [IF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364) and you're there.

Comment: Please add a example of your attempts to create the formula.

Comment: @Tedinoz I think the problem with the question is he starts off with "if cell A1 has a date in it" but when you read to the bottom of the question it looks like he doesn't care if it is a date and just wants to have an override column.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to first delete excess rows before using arrayformulas... for example if you have 100 rows of data make sure you don't have more than 200 rows in your speadsheet... (highlight right click and delete excess rows) The following formula will do what you are asking for assuming row 1 is headers.

Paste the following in cell F1

```
=arrayformula({"Final Date";if(B2:B="",A2:A,B2:B)})
```